# custom wordpress post field for download pdf button

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am attempting to create custom field that allows users to login into wordpress dashboard > edit post > upload a pdf > and after publish the post; which will then have a working 'download PDF' button.

I have created the custom field and the option is there to toggle 'PDF' and attach a PDF document. The button appears as it should after publish -- but upon clicking the link doesn't work. Below is my added code that should be working for this functionality. Any suggestions?

```
    <?php  $pdf_val = get_custom_field('pdfdoc:get_post','guid');
        if($pdf_val){ ?>
        <div style="text-align: center;"><button class="downloadBtn" style="color: #ffffff !important;"><a href="<?php print_custom_field('pdfdoc:get_post','guid'); ?>"><span style="color: #fff !important;">Download PDF</span></a></strong></button></div>
        <?php }  ?>
```

**Also it is to be noted that within the source, the a tag is actually being populated with the PDF file! But the click doesn't fire? =/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was.. for those who may be interested..

Removing of `<button>` wrapping the `<a>` tag.